# Deploying Object fields in Big Object

Tags: deployment, workbench, big-object

Does anyone know whether it is possible to deploy custom or standard object into big object without **manually** writing those entire object fields and permission set file?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like possible. There are no document which mention this.

Also there are many difference between existing object and big objects. For example there naming conventions is different. From docs:

> Object names must be unique across all standard objects, custom
>   objects, external objects, and big objects in the org. In the API, the
>   names of custom big objects have a suffix of two underscores
>   immediately followed by a lowercase “b” (__b). For example, an
>   external object named “HistoricalInventoryLevels” is seen as
>   HistoricalInventoryLevels__b in that organization's WSDL.

Also You must use the Metadata API to define or add a field to a custom big object. You can’t do it through the UI. So you might need to manually add them in permission set.

Permissionset/profile files — Create a permissionSet or profile file to specify permissions for each field. These files are not required, but is required to grant access to users. By default, access to a custom big object is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring '19 it's possible to create deploy Big Objects from Setup. Before that release, it was only possible through Metadata API.

> ## [Create Custom Big Objects from Setup](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_data_big_object_setup.htm)
>
> A big object stores and manages a massive amount of data natively on the Salesforce platform. You can archive data from other objects or bring massive datasets from outside systems into a big object to get a full view of your customers. Big objects provide consistent performance, whether you have 1 million records, 100 million, or even 1 billion. Previously, creating a big object required using Metadata API. But now, if you aren’t comfortable using the API, you can create a big object in Setup, define its fields, and build the index that defines how the big object is queried.